# Create Circular Bar and Custom Swipe for TableView Cell in Swift 5?

Tags: uitableview, swipe, swift5

[image]

How to Create above Yellow, Green and Red Circular in `UITableViewCell` and also custom swipe from right to left with `Edit` and `Delete` in Swift?